# CQ 5.4 to CQ 5.6.1 LDAPLoginModule

Tags: maven, aem

In CQ 5.4 I created a custom LDAP Login Module by extending com.day.crx.security.ldap.LDAPLoginModule

This was added to my maven project with the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.day.crx</groupId>
    <artifactId>crx-auth-ldap</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

All was fine and things work as expected. Moving the code to 5.6.1 I had to implement the same code in an OSGI bundle, but there is a problem in that the dependency is no longer resolved. Dependency finder returns no record of the class or dependency, although it must be there somewhere as you can set up a standard LDAP login using this class.

***Does anyone know the correct dependency for this class in 5.6.1?***

Answer (score 0):

In CQ 5.4.1 you had write your own LDAP login module.
LDAP integration can be done with just doing proper configuration.
 This customization not required in 5.6.1. Please see the documentation at  https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/core/administering/ldap_authentication.html
 and also there is more help available at --> https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/LdapConfig.html

Comment: No need to write your own in 5.4 if the provided on works fine. The LDAPLoginModule I mention is available out of the box. Our problem is slow sync of groups (for reasons out of our control at the LDAP provider end), so we extended it to handle group sync in our own way. `com.day.crx.security.ldap.LDAPLoginModule` is available to use is 5.6.1, but I don't seem to be able to extend it. Looking at work arounds now (or will when this moves back up the priority list).

Answer (score 0):

Seems that dependency version-->2.3.5 for the artifactId-->crx-auth-ldap in your pom.xml is no longer maintained at at  nexus repsository of adobe for CQ-5.6.1
I found the below dependency details with updated version details in -->https://repo.adobe.com/nexus/content/groups/public/com/day/cq/cq-quickstart-product-dependencies/5.6.1/cq-quickstart-product-dependencies-5.6.1.pom

```html
<dependency>
<groupId>com.day.crx</groupId>
<artifactId>crx-auth-ldap</artifactId>
<version>2.4.30</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Please retry with this modified version.

Or share your complete bundle code by using any placing it in 'drop-box' (https://www.dropbox.com/) Let me check the issue properly